# What is the format of the public key in GetParametersForImport in AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

AWS KMS method "GetParametersForImport" returns a public key of Type: Base64-encoded binary data object.

Does any one know What is the format of this public key? Is it an X509? or something else.

How to read and import this key in .net 4.8 as [RSA.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-6.0) is available in .net 6.0 and newer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersForImport.html#API_GetParametersForImport_ResponseSyntax

Tried
[ImportCspBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob?view=netframework-4.8) but its not working.